# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Adldap\Adldap\Configuration\DomainConfiguration'

Tags: php, linux, ldap, apache2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Adldap\Adldap\Configuration\DomainConfiguration' not found in /var/www/html/accounts/ad/accounts.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/accounts/ad.php(15): include() #1 /var/www/html/accounts/index.php(72): include('/var/www/html/a...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/accounts/ad/accounts.php on line 6

accounts.php =

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Adldap\Adldap;
use Adldap\Utilities;

$config = new Adlap\Configuration\DomainConfiguration([
'hosts' => [
         'XXXXXXXXXX',
],
]);


$ad = new \Adldap\Adldap();
$ad->addProvider($config);

try {
$provider = $ad->connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure is exits Adldap\Adldap php package also for this you need install composer tool. . If it doesn't exits then add name of package to composer.json like this:

**composer require vendor/package**

For show installed packages enter:

**composer show -i**

After it you can use package easly.

Comment: Ok, in composer.json It was written adldap2/adldap2 : 8.4 but it was the bad version, then I replaced 8.4 by my current adldap2 version which is 10.4.2. A new error occured Uncaught Error: Class 'Adldap\Configuration\DomainConfiguration' not found, it's not "Adldap\Adldap" anymore but juste "Adldap", I think I'm on the right way, but how can I put the code "composer require vendor/package" in composer.json ?

Comment: no dude) needn't put "composer require vendor/package" in composer.json. If you want to write it in composer.json put it to requires block , For example {.... "requires" : { "adldap/adldap":"*" ..} ...  }  . Dots has written instead other letter, that is dont write whole these :)

Comment: ok I realised it just after I posted the comment lmaooo , i tried to make composer require vendor/package on the shell but it didn't work

Comment: What operation system do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu server I can show you my code if you want to